# How do I format HTML code in Code Mirror when the value is set to it?

Tags: codemirror

I am using the Code Mirror plugin to edit HTML source of a page. The HTML code is fetched from database and set as value in Code Mirror. But, after setting the value it is displayed in the same format in which it was saved in the database. How can I display it in proper format? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a function called `autoFormatRange`

```
editor.autoFormatRange(range.from, range.to);
```

This fragment from the [CodeMirror Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/codemirror/HZlnNr4_JHI) might be what you need:

```
function autoFormat() {
    var totalLines = editor.lineCount();
    var totalChars = editor.getTextArea().value.length;
    editor.autoFormatRange({line:0, ch:0}, {line:totalLines, ch:totalChars});
}
```

http://codemirror.net/2/demo/formatting.html

Comment: I have used the above code, but there is some problem while setting a huge data in the codemirror can something be done for that?

Comment: The autoFormatRange method seems to be gone

Comment: Yes, ty.However it has been removed since 3.11: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/codemirror/how%2420to%2420manage%2420formatting/codemirror/hdEWC83r94c/PcaVazYL9PAJ

Comment: It was removed, so you can use custom extension http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109809/codemirror-auto-format-after-setvalue/35272479#35272479