# Auto format CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I'm populating my CodeMirror textarea with an unformatted string of CSS. I have no control over the formatting of this CSS.

**Unformatted CSS example**

```
position: absolute; top: 66px; left: 746px; width: 399px; height: 353px; background-color: pink;
```

When I set that string as the value of the CodeMirror textarea, it looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I've tried [AutoFormatDateRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892500/how-do-i-format-the-html-code-in-code-mirror-when-the-value-is-set-to-it) but I think that function has been removed?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `.autoFormatRange()`, but I think your CSS has to be wrapped in `<style></style>` tags for CodeMirror to know how to format your string.

**Edit**

I haven't used CodeMirror this way myself, but inserting your string here didn't work:

http://codemirror.net/2/demo/formatting.html

But when wrapping it in `<style></style>` it was formated as expected.

Comment: .autoFormatRange() is an extension inside /lib/util/formatting.js and was removed as of Version 3.11 (20-Mar-2013).  I've tried using that code anyway within v3.20 and it partially works, but there's an error I don't feel like debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This project seems to implement a CSS (and JS, and HTML) pretty-printer in JavaScript:

https://github.com/einars/js-beautify

So run the code through that before putting it into the editor.