# Codemirror Auto Format after setValue

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

http://liveweave.com/UxEJ0s

I'm using Codemirror for my app.

I noticed if I select all the text and press SHIFT+Tab it will auto align my code making it easier to read.

Here's an example of what my app currently renders:

```
<ul>
<li>
<font color="#f90000">
  Apples
</font>
</li>
<li>
<font color="#ff9a3d">
  Oranges
</font>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I'm trying to get it to render:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <font color="#f90000">
      Apples
    </font>
  </li>
  <li>
    <font color="#ff9a3d">
      Oranges
    </font>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Edit

Does anyone know if there's a way to do this without selecting the whole code manually in Codemirror?

Why? I have Codemirror running in my background of my app all code that's added is added dynamically, but when I save the final code it looks like above.

Comment: I can see from the given Url (http://liveweave.com/UxEJ0s) that It's already getting rendered what you wanted to by pressing Shift-tab on the selected text.
Can you please be specific for what you want to achieve?

Comment: I revised my post and explained more specifically on what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: AutoFormat is no longer part of the current CodeMirror. See the comment from the developer Marijn Haverbeke  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codemirror/1HOXA2Q7oDk

Comment: autoFormatRange is deprecated. So instead I'm now using jsBeautify available here - https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`autoFormatRange` **was removed** from codemirror, so we should use another way, register our own extension:

**1. generate js**

Go to js generator (just an easy way to get minified js with plugins and custom extensions). <strike>http://codemirror.net/doc/compress.html</strike>

Updated link for version 3: http://codemirror.net/3/doc/compress.html

**2. Select options desired**

Paste custom extension code and press "*Compress*" button.

```
CodeMirror.defineExtension("autoFormatRange", function (from, to) {
    var cm = this;
    var outer = cm.getMode(), text = cm.getRange(from, to).split("\n");
    var state = CodeMirror.copyState(outer, cm.getTokenAt(from).state);
    var tabSize = cm.getOption("tabSize");

    var out = "", lines = 0, atSol = from.ch == 0;
    function newline() {
        out += "\n";
        atSol = true;
        ++lines;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; ++i) {
        var stream = new CodeMirror.StringStream(text[i], tabSize);
        while (!stream.eol()) {
            var inner = CodeMirror.innerMode(outer, state);
            var style = outer.token(stream, state), cur = stream.current();
            stream.start = stream.pos;
            if (!atSol || /\S/.test(cur)) {
                out += cur;
                atSol = false;
            }
            if (!atSol && inner.mode.newlineAfterToken &&
                inner.mode.newlineAfterToken(style, cur, stream.string.slice(stream.pos) || text[i+1] || "", inner.state))
                newline();
        }
        if (!stream.pos && outer.blankLine) outer.blankLine(state);
        if (!atSol) newline();
    }

    cm.operation(function () {
        cm.replaceRange(out, from, to);
        for (var cur = from.line + 1, end = from.line + lines; cur <= end; ++cur)
            cm.indentLine(cur, "smart");
    });
});

// Applies automatic mode-aware indentation to the specified range
CodeMirror.defineExtension("autoIndentRange", function (from, to) {
    var cmInstance = this;
    this.operation(function () {
        for (var i = from.line; i <= to.line; i++) {
            cmInstance.indentLine(i, "smart");
        }
    });
});
```

**3. Use generated .js as follows**

Html:

```
<textarea id=code><?=$value?></textarea>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/codemirror/codemirror.css">
<script src="/codemirror/codemirror-compressed.js"></script>
<script>
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: "text/html"
});
var totalLines = editor.lineCount();  
editor.autoFormatRange({line:0, ch:0}, {line:totalLines});
</script>
```

Code was found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codemirror/1HOXA2Q7oDk)

Comment: the link to the compress tool is broken

Comment: That online uglify has been shut down - "Service discontinued" when you hit Compress

Answer (score 13):

Ever since Codemirror has removed support for `autoFormatRange()` it's not worth the trouble to use it for formatting text. I use `js-beautify` instead.

```
var beautify_js = require('js-beautify').js_beautify
var beautify_html = require('js-beautify').html

var formattedJSON = beautify_js(jsonText, { indent_size: 2 });
var formattedXML = beautify_html(xmlText, { indent_size: 2 });
```

Comment: autoFormatRange is deprecated. So instead I'm now using jsBeautify available here - http://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify

Comment: do you use it in python or what?

Comment: No just Javascript

Comment: Also using jsbeautify. It works the way you would have hoped the Codemirror built-in and now-deprecated formatting would work. And it's not kludgy, it's really quite simple as in the example above.

Comment: Just to add on to the code example with some codemirror: You'll want to get your instance of codemirror and do something like this:

`codeMirrorInstance.setValue(html_beautify(codeMirrorInstance.getValue()));`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code to achieve what you want :

```
function format() {
    var totalLines = editor.lineCount();  
    editor.autoFormatRange({line:0, ch:0}, {line:totalLines});
}
```

Bind this function with your events, and it will auto-format the code.

Answer (score 3):

By using `codemirror` formatting add-on you can achieve your requirement

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Wg52/71/)

```
 var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        mode: "htmlmixed",
        extraKeys:{"Shift-Tab":autoFormatSelection}
      });


      function getSelectedRange() {
        return { from: editor.getCursor(true), to: editor.getCursor(false) };
      }

      function autoFormatSelection() {
        var range = getSelectedRange();
        editor.autoFormatRange(range.from, range.to);
      }
```

Source Link

http://codemirror.net/2/demo/formatting.html

Comment: @shubhamkes corrected the broken fiddle link. Check now
http://jsfiddle.net/7Wg52/71/

Comment: I realize this is old, but the formatting doesn't do anything anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the original addon including a small update to let it work with CodeMirror V3 :

```
CodeMirror.extendMode("css", {
    commentStart: "/*",
    commentEnd: "*/",
    newlineAfterToken: function(type, content) {
        return /^[;{}]$/.test(content);
    }
});

CodeMirror.extendMode("javascript", {
    commentStart: "/*",
    commentEnd: "*/",    
    newlineAfterToken: function(type, content, textAfter, state) {
        if (this.jsonMode) {
            return /^[\[,{]$/.test(content) || /^}/.test(textAfter);
        } else {
            if (content == ";" && state.lexical && state.lexical.type == ")") return false;
        return /^[;{}]$/.test(content) && !/^;/.test(textAfter);
        }
    }
});

CodeMirror.extendMode("xml", {
    commentStart: "<!--",
    commentEnd: "-->",
    newlineAfterToken: function(type, content, textAfter) {    
        return ( type == "tag" && />$/.test(content) || /^</.test(textAfter) ) || (  type == "tag bracket" && />$/.test(content) );
    }
});


CodeMirror.defineExtension("commentRange", function (isComment, from, to) {
    var cm = this, curMode = CodeMirror.innerMode(cm.getMode(), cm.getTokenAt(from).state).mode;
    cm.operation(function() {
        if (isComment) { // Comment range
            cm.replaceRange(curMode.commentEnd, to);
            cm.replaceRange(curMode.commentStart, from);
        if (from.line == to.line && from.ch == to.ch) // An empty comment inserted - put cursor inside
            cm.setCursor(from.line, from.ch + curMode.commentStart.length);
        } else { // Uncomment range
            var selText = cm.getRange(from, to);
            var startIndex = selText.indexOf(curMode.commentStart);
            var endIndex = selText.lastIndexOf(curMode.commentEnd);
            if (startIndex > -1 && endIndex > -1 && endIndex > startIndex) {
                // Take string till comment start
                selText = selText.substr(0, startIndex)
                // From comment start till comment end
                + selText.substring(startIndex + curMode.commentStart.length, endIndex)
                // From comment end till string end
                + selText.substr(endIndex + curMode.commentEnd.length);
            }
            cm.replaceRange(selText, from, to);
        }
    });
});


CodeMirror.defineExtension("autoIndentRange", function (from, to) {
    var cmInstance = this;
    this.operation(function () {
        for (var i = from.line; i <= to.line; i++) {
            cmInstance.indentLine(i, "smart");
        }
    });
});


CodeMirror.defineExtension("autoFormatRange", function (from, to) {
    var cm = this;
    var outer = cm.getMode(), text = cm.getRange(from, to).split("\n");        
    var state = CodeMirror.copyState(outer, cm.getTokenAt(from).state);
    var tabSize = cm.getOption("tabSize");

    var out = "", lines = 0, atSol = from.ch == 0;
    function newline() {
      out += "\n";
      atSol = true;
      ++lines;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; ++i) {
      var stream = new CodeMirror.StringStream(text[i], tabSize);      
      while (!stream.eol()) {
        var inner = CodeMirror.innerMode(outer, state);   
        var style = outer.token(stream, state), cur = stream.current();
        stream.start = stream.pos;
        if (!atSol || /\S/.test(cur)) {
          out += cur;
          atSol = false;
        }

        if (!atSol && inner.mode.newlineAfterToken &&
            inner.mode.newlineAfterToken(style, cur, stream.string.slice(stream.pos) || text[i+1] || "", inner.state))
          newline();        
      }
      if (!stream.pos && outer.blankLine) outer.blankLine(state);
      if (!atSol)newline();
    }

    cm.operation(function () {
      cm.replaceRange(out, from, to);
      for (var cur = from.line + 1, end = from.line + lines; cur <= end; ++cur)
        cm.indentLine(cur, "smart");
      cm.setSelection(from, cm.getCursor(false));
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution also works with CodeMirror v5

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but maybe this can help someone who faces the same issue

autoFormatRange is not available anymore, however it is possible to indent the editor's value line by line, and no need to select the content

```
editor.eachLine(line => {
   editor.indentLine(editor.getLineNumber(line), "smart");
})
```