# SQL autoformatting in codeMirror

Tags: javascript, sql, codemirror

I'm trying to "beautify" sql code in [codeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) .

Autoformatting in not supported in codeMirror since v2 (current version is v4)

I've tried to use the old module formatting.js with autoFormatRange function ( [the previous question on StackOverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109809/codemirror-auto-format-after-setvalue)). It doesn't seem to work properly with SQL. It makes indentation without any linebreaks

Did anyone figure out how to get this feature working on codeMirror v4 with SQL?

Answer (score 8):

I've solved the problem using this js auto-formatter : https://github.com/zeroturnaround/sql-formatter

It does an excellent job at formatting SQL ([demo here](https://zeroturnaround.github.io/sql-formatter/))

Comment: Link to demo doesn't work but this may be an alternate:  [demo](https://sql-formatter-org.github.io/sql-formatter/)